# Add optional gzip compression to selfhosted WCF service

Tags: wcf, rest, gzip, custom-attributes

How can I add a optional gzip compression for my selfhosted WCF service? I'm using for this senario the `WebHttpBinding`. I want to check if the `Accept` header contains the string `gzip` and compress than the content.

I would like to use a custom Attribute. So far I curriently use a custom Attribute allows me to switch between XML and JSON output, but I have just now no idea how to compress the output.

In my encoder switch attribute I implemented the `IDispatchMessageFormatter` interface to change on demand the `XmlObjectSerializer`. But I don't unterstand how the output is generated to modify it.

It would be nice if somebody could point my to a possible solution.

Comment: Interesting question. Why does it have to be optional? Just curious. I thought gzip compression was a standard supported in pretty much all devices that use http, so my hosted WCF services do it at the IIS configuration level.

Comment: It would be nice so it's easier to test the service via telnet. Also I'm not sure if it is easy for a third party client to handle the compression.

Comment: Ah, you might want to try Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to test your WCF http services. It's awesome. I haven't run across a device that doesn't automatically decompress gzip yet, but I guess I can't say for sure if all third party clients can handle it either.

Comment: You still have a perfectly valid question, of course. Just thought it might save you some time if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an attribute, but it is the basic code that will compress WCF service responses, and can be wrapped up into an attribute if desired.

```
public static void CompressResponseStream(HttpContext context = null)
{
    if (context == null)
        context = HttpContext.Current;

    string encodings = context.Request.Headers.Get("Accept-Encoding");

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(encodings))
    {
        encodings = encodings.ToLowerInvariant();

        if (encodings.Contains("deflate"))
        {
            context.Response.Filter = new DeflateStream(context.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
            context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
            context.Response.AppendHeader("X-CompressResponseStream", "deflate");
        }
        else if (encodings.Contains("gzip"))
        {
            context.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(context.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
            context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
            context.Response.AppendHeader("X-CompressResponseStream", "gzip");
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.AppendHeader("X-CompressResponseStream", "no-known-accept");
        }
    }
}
```

[EDIT] to address comments:

Simply call it anywhere in the body of your web service operation, as it sets properties on the response:

```
[OperationContract]
public ReturnType GetInformation(...) {
    // do some stuff
    CompressResponseStream();
}
```

Comment: Well I dropped that project, but that looks really good. If you could provide an example where your function should be called I will accept your answer.